# Open Nautilus at "+ Other Locations" from terminal

Tags: linux, nautilus

**Is there a way to open "Nautilus" (in Debian/Ubuntu) at the window "+ Other Locations" from command-line**

Neither manual nor --help states anything about such

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ nautilus other-locations:///
```

Comment: The threatstarter answerd his own question. and it worked.